# Looking for a concrete example of Hyperbolic groups

Tags: geometry, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

### Background

On page 232 of [1], the authors mentioned a few examples of Fuchsian groups that could be explicitly written down, namely, four cyclic groups; Hyperbolic, Parabolic, Elliptic, and Modular. Yet, they haven't put concrete examples of each so I started working on myself and I got stuck at understanding hyperbolic cyclic groups.

### Question

From the wiki, I understood the definition of hyperbolic cyclic groups [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group#:%7E:text=and%20many%20others.-,Definition,-%5Bedit%5D). And it seems the Dihedral group of order 8 (as it's a finitely generated group of Mobius transformations, rotations and reflections) meet the definition.
But I was not sure why it's called `Hyperbolic`... could someone explain it to me?

### Reference

[1] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Elements of $(P)SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ are classified as hyperbolic, parabolic, or elliptic based on their trace/conjugacy class/action on the real line or upper half-plane, etc.  The geometry of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is hyperbolic geometry (it can be viewed as the unit tangent bundle of the hyperbolic plane).  Fuchsian groups are discrete subgroups of $(P)SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, discrete groups of isometries of the hyperbolic plane.  Hyperbolic groups in the geometric group theory sense, while not unrelated, are a general class of groups satisfying certain growth conditions.